# Go chi.URLParam returning empty string

Tags: go, http, url-parameters, go-chi

I'm new to Go so I'm trying to build a simple CRUD API using Chi. In the `GetById` handler I'm using `chi.URLParam()` method to retrieve data from the URL, but this method is returning an empty string "". Check the code:

```golang
func GetBookByIDHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    db, err := repository.OpenConnection()
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        log.Printf("Error while opening connection: %v", err)
        return
    }
    defer db.Close()

    repo := repository.NewBookSQLRepository(db)
    useCase := usecases.NewFindBookByIDUseCase(repo)

    idParam := chi.URLParam(r, "id")
    //idParams = ""

    var input usecases.FindBookByIDInput
    input.ID = idParam

    output, err := useCase.FindBookByID(input)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        log.Printf("Error while getting book by id: %v", err)
        return
    }

    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(output)
}
```

My router is built as follows:

```golang
    r := chi.NewRouter()
    r.Get("/books", handlers.GetAllBooksHandler)
    r.Get("/books/{id}", handlers.GetBookByIDHandler)
    r.Post("/books", handlers.CreateBookHandler)
```

I'm using Insomnia for the HTTP requests, in the following URL:
http://localhost:8080/books/10

I already tried to make the request passing query params as `"?id=10"` but it did not work.

Comment: Please share a [**minimal, reproducable**, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). [This](https://go.dev/play/p/V0PgVTaT-Bt) works as expected for me (if I access `http://localhost:3000/books/10` it outputs `requested ID 10`; I'd guess your issue is in code you have not shown us).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the exact same issue and there's no answers for me, but I do I have a workaround which extracts the id in the conventional way, below is the working version of your code:

```
func GetBookByIDHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    db, err := repository.OpenConnection()
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        log.Printf("Error while opening connection: %v", err)
        return
    }
    defer db.Close()

    repo := repository.NewBookSQLRepository(db)
    useCase := usecases.NewFindBookByIDUseCase(repo)

    // Split the URL path and extract the book id
    parts := strings.Split(r.URL.Path, "/")
    if len(parts) < 2 {
        logger.Error(fmt.Sprintf("GetBookByID, Book ID not found"))
        WriteJSON(w, http.StatusBadRequest, models.Response[any]{
            Success: false,
            Message: fmt.Sprintf("Book ID not found"),
        })
        return
    }

    idParams := parts[2]

    // Assuming your book id is defined as integer in your database
    id, err := strconv.Atoi(idParams)
    if err != nil {
        logger.Error(fmt.Sprintf("GetBookByID, invalid ID: %s", id))
        WriteJSON(w, http.StatusBadRequest, models.Response[any]{
            Success: false,
            Message: fmt.Sprintf("invalid ID: %s", id),
        })
        return
    }

    var input usecases.FindBookByIDInput
    input.ID = id

    output, err := useCase.FindBookByID(input)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        log.Printf("Error while getting book by id: %v", err)
        return
    }

    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(output)
   }
}
```